# How do I print out a group of elements in a certain way?

Tags: python-2.7

```
    items = {'b': 'Bike', 'm': 'Motorcycle', 'd': 'Dresser', 't': 'Trailer', 'c': 'Car',}

while True:
    print "1. Add an item."
    print "2. Find an item."
    print "3. Print the message board."
    print "4. Quit."
    choice = input("Enter your selection: ")
    if choice == 1:
        item = raw_input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:")
        cost = raw_input("Enter the item cost:")
        elts = []
        elts.append([items[item],cost])
    if choice == 2:
        itemType = raw_input("Enter the item type=b,m,d,t,c:")
        itemCost = raw_input("Enter maximum item cost:")
        if itemType == item and itemCost <= cost:
            print "Sold ", itemType, "for", itemCost
    if choice == 3:
        print str(elts) + ':'
    if choice == 4:
        print elts
        break
```

I tried printing the str(elts) with adding a : to seperate it but im fairly new to this and dont know how to display the elements in a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new list (`elts`) every time you insert an item.

Try this:

```
elts = [] # Create the list here
while True:
    ...
    if choice == 1:
        item = raw_input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:")
        cost = raw_input("Enter the item cost:")
        # And just append the new element
        # btw, you were appending a list
        # Perhaps this is what you need
        elts.append((items[item], cost)) # Append a tuple
    ...
```

And then you can work with the list of tuples the way you like it:

Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
if choice == 3:
    print ['{0}:{1}'.format(item, cost) for item, cost in elts]
```

Using [reduce()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
if choice == 3:
    print reduce(lambda t1, t2: '{0}:{1}, {2}:{3}'.format(t1[0], t1[1], t2[0], t2[1]), elts)
```

**UPDATE**

Also you can fix your second condition with this:

```
if any([items[itemType] == i and itemCost <= c for i, c in elts]):
    print "Sold ", items[itemType], "for", itemCost
```

Comment: Yes this did work thank you although I am trying to print it in a format of itemType, ":". itemCost

Comment: Did you see the example using list comprehensions @FrankValdez? You can modify the string format for each tuple the way you want

Comment: Maybe you are trying to print the sum of all costs for each item Type, is that correct?

Comment: No im just trying to print all items individually.

Comment: I edited my answer, change your `if choice == 3` condition with any of my examples

Comment: Also for when I use the 2nd option to look for an item it prints out as b or d instead of dresser or bike. How do i fix this?

Comment: Check my answer again, i made an update, you need to print `items[itemType]` not `itemType`